# Compare two dates and times in excel to return the max biggest of two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, excel-2010, vlookup

How do I return the most recent of two date columns, columns also contain N/As.
Does the columns have to be in a certain format? Does it have to be date only and time only or can I calculated the max with both values in the same column?

Example

```
2018-12-01 18:00:00:000   2017-12-01 17:00:00:000
2016-12-01 17:00:00:000   2018-12-01 14:00:00:000
2018-12-01 15:00:00:000   2017-12-01 12:00:00:000
2018-12-01 15:00:00:000   #N/A
```

so for the above I want to return

```
2018-12-01 18:00:00:000 
2018-12-01 14:00:00:000
2018-12-01 15:00:00:000
2018-12-01 15:00:00:000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE, substituting the third `:` for `.` so Excel can format it as time:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,--SUBSTITUTE(A1:B1,":",".",3),1)
```

then format the output column as:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to see someone who doesn't answer in comments.

Comment: I probably do that too much.

Comment: THIS WORKED PERFECT. Thank you very much! :)